# Requirement to develop scalable web application

Tags: load-balancing, scalability, paas, appscale

We're planning to develop a web based Healthcare Practice Management System. Due to [HIPAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act) we're requested to deploy the app in our own premises. Our company is relatively small currently we have only software engineers and no devops engineers but still we want to develop the application to support horizontal scaling(adding more servers).

Planned to use:

- Python3 (Django)
- PostgreSQL

I'm looking for something like *AppScale* but with the freedom of choosing our own runtime, database and frameworks.

In other words from the software engineer's perspective:

- Should provide an easy way to deploy django application
- Should have web based dashboard to monitor and control(like AppScale)
- Should make load balancing simple (app and database)

Comment: Just down voting is not helpful at all. It would be great if I know what rule that I violated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) which is a container orchestration technology specifically designed for [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and also found that scaling is not just the responsibility of platform that the app is deployed on but also its depends on how the app is designed and coded. For that [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) methodology is really helpful.

But I can't deploy database on Kubernetes because its not recommended by Kelsey Hightower(author of Kubernetes Up and Running) in his [talk](https://youtu.be/gf43TcWjBrE?t=17m57s). So, for now I chose to  deploy my database on a VM.

Answer (score 3):

**[AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/why-appscale/)** implements the **[Google App Engine APIs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/)** which, IMHO, make it super easy to develop web apps quickly and efficiently.
On top of that, you get **auto-scaling**, **load balancing**, and the ability to **deploy on-premises** and plug in **any third-party library** you need. 
AppScale already comes with a **dashboard** and will soon be launching a new management service for your AppScale deployment(s).

If you're not particularly hung up on Python3 and PostgreSQL, all of the above seem to cover your requirements.

It's worth noting that opting for the GAE model means you opt for NoSQL and, so, postgres is probably not the best option.

*Disclaimer: I'm part of the AppScale team and we're already helping companies develop and deliver their apps in the HIPAA compliance realm.*

Comment: I don't have any experience in NoSQL so please correct me if I'm wrong. What I heard about NoSQL is that its only good for chart, forums, etc., in other words application which don't worry about data loss and don't require any complex queries which involves JOINs. I can switch to Python2 but have to use a RDBMS. So, If I use MySQL(Cloud SQL) instead PostgreSQL will the AppScale help in auto-scaling and load balancing.

Comment: You can set up MySQL on AppScale and use it from within your app. However, you essentially won't be using the Datastore API as there is currently no Datastore to MySQL translation layer.
AppScale's NoSQL backend is Cassandra which is highly scalable and efficient. Regarding data loss, AppScale offers data replication like GAE as well as backups. As for JOINs, there are limitations ([GAE docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/), [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810303/without-joins-on-google-app-engine-does-your-data-have-to-exist-in-one-big-tabl))

Comment: That's not a problem because we're going to use [Django](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-django-skeleton) which provides a nice ORM for MySQL. But my question is do the AppScale helps in scaling MySQL simple as [this](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/FAQs#what-is-a-recommended-production-deployment) just specifying multiple IPs.

Comment: AppScale does not provide automatic scaling for MySQL because it doesn't know about it. You'd have to configure that manually.